# Lorentz Invariance of Fermionic Bilinear Covariants

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, lorentz-symmetry

I am working in a fermionic theory and trying to show the Lorentz covariance of the associated bilinear covariants (ie. a scalar and a 3-vector).

$\psi^{\dagger}\psi$ $\:\:\psi^{\dagger}\mathbf{\alpha}\psi$

where alpha is $
   M=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   0 & {\sigma} \\
   {\sigma} & 0 \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$

I am familiar with the arguments used for showing that the standard bilinear spinor products transform correctly under Lorentz transformations but this relies on the vector being a 4-vector and on the scalar being the adjoint of $\psi$ multiplying $\psi$ (rather than the dagger).  I'm not sure how best to show it in this situation, so any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: As in your other question, it will help immensely if you describe/write out what $\alpha$ is in your question.

Comment: Added as request, $\alpha$ is a 4x4 matrix which I have defined in my post.

Comment: How does $\psi$ transform under Lorentz transformations?